# Physical Firewall with seperation

Tags: networking

I am not sure how to exactly describe this but I am looking for manufacturers and recommendations that could reduce my footprint in my current environment. I currently have 4 physical firewalls providing separation in our environment.

I was told that there were manufacturers that could offer me the separation of having multiple firewalls but under one physical chassis. Is this something that exists? I tried Googling this but wasn't sure how to phrase the search.

By the way, I am not referring to zoning, I am referring to actual physical separation but under a single chassis.

Comment: This question is better for presales staff at the various network hardware manufacturers. Try reaching out to them directly. That being said, your question needs more detail. There are certainly blade/chassis firewalls that would meet your objective though they can be physically large and expensive.

Comment: 'Physical' separation? You are going to have to explain that phrase. Also, it is possible to use the same firewall and loop the traffic back onto itself. In your case, loop it back 4 times. No special hardware needed, just enough ports. I've done this.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. What I mean by physical separation is a chassis having network ports and configs that are separate from one another. As an example, think of the functionality that two firewalls sitting side by side would provide and now assume all of that exactly as is under one chassis.

Comment: No there aren't any that wont cost you an arm and a leg. Why not just use 1 firewall with multiple ports? If your environment is small enough you could use a router/L3switch with an access-list